# Cannot upload project in public_html directory

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have a shared hosting i have created test_project folder inside public_html directory, when i access it through url i'm getting

[image]

myurl is like :

```
https://maindomain.com/testproject/,
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks as though you need to use the public subdirectory as the web root - try https://maindomain.com/testproject/public

Comment: @NigelRen: Thanks it is working can i remove public from the url

Comment: Sure. You will need to implement an internal rewriting rule for that. Which rewrites all requests to the base folder into the public folder. You will find lots of examples here on SO. And you definitely should take a look into the documentation of the apache rewriting module.